# Android - How to avoid repetition of values before inserting in SqliteDB?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app, i am supposed to log values for all days of the week..Sat,sun,mon etc and i am supposed to plot values in a graph to show some statistics..So while logging, if i have already logged for that day of the week previously, how do i delete it ?and then log new values?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is allready created and if it is, then use  UPDATE to overwrite the new data :-)

Comment: yea..thts the basic principle ... but here the person can open the app and should be loggin values throughout, so every time a person opens the app during that day, it will get overwritten....